# How many significant figures to quote my answer for computer generated values and uncertainty?

Tags: error-analysis

I have to write a code to find the optimal temperature and optimal intensity (and their uncertainties) for a computer-generated blackbody spectrum. For the spectrum, the given values for the frequencies, the intensity and its uncertainties are quoted to 14 significant figures. These are my results from the program:

- Optimal T=9321.239288916953+/-24.415825700724287,
- optimal I_0=122.71809644650259+/-1.0273461740403342

I have to 'quote my value and its uncertainty to the correct number of significant figures (bearing in mind that to quote an uncertainty to *n* significant figures usually required of the order of
$$
\frac{10^{2n}+2}{2}
$$
independent measurements.'

I don't know what that means or what exactly I have to do with that equation.
I just want to know how many significant figures I have to quote my values and their uncertainty to exactly. I know it has to be less significant figures than the stated value.

Comment: What are the uncertainties of the other quantities you used as input in your calculations?

Comment: # Frequency (Hz): 1.000000000000000000e+13  
corrected Intensity (arb units): -2.679775821420815563e-08 ± 6.530721531432347393e-08

This is one of the data set with the uncertainty. all are within 6.530721 limit.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).